# No scrolling since adding slide-in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Since adding a slide-in menu to my web page the rest of the page doesn't seem to be able to scroll to remaining content at the bottom of the page? This is more noticeable if you resize the browser to make the height smaller.

http://handmade-nation.com/dev/v3/shop.html

I think the reason is down to the fixed position and 100% height on the #right div but if this is removed it knocks out the menu so I need help working around this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we have a js fiddle of some CSS or HTML? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` in your `#right` it solved the issue for me in my browser.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I've spent the last couple of night trying to fix that!